# Can I transfer a high-cost premium level domain to take advantage of new lower prices for that TLD?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains, domain-transfer

I purchased a premium tld last year from a registrar, let's say I got `mysite.awesome`.  At that time, `.awesome` tld was going for $200/year.

Time to renew has come, and `.awesome` sites have dropped to $40/year.

My registrar is forcing me to pay $200 this year because as they say "The renewal cost was set by the `.awesome` registry. Different registries price renewal costs differently for premium domains."
What does that mean?  If I transfer the domain to another registrar, will I be able to pay $40 or am I stuck at $200 since it was "set by the `.awesome` registry"?

Answer (score 2):

Premium prices depend per registry. Some registries do indeed lock the price at time of registration and all renewals will be at same price. Other registries make you pay higher for the first registration of the domain, but then renewals are priced like any other domain.

In short, it all depends on the TLD. You should ask your current registrar for explanation, or the registry, or any other registrar you wish to transfer to, it should be able to explain to you the process and the cost involved.

Comment: thanks...it seems the price got locked at time of registration.  It stinks that renewals will be at same price even though current price for that TLD is much much lower.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, probably not.  I'd guess the domain also has a premium transfer price, in line with the $200 registration fee you paid.

Regular (non premium) .AWESOME domains likely have that $40 price you see.  All registrations haven't dropped.

There are different types of premium domain names, and the type is determined by the Registry.

Some premium domains have a high initial cost but a regular renewal/transfer cost (many .TV domains).

Some premium domains have a high initial and high renewal/transfer price (an example of this is .WS domains).

There are likely extensions that fall in the middle of these two, but generally, a premium is one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but why don't you just visit the another registrar's website and check out the price? It will show you the domain transfer price when you add your domain to the cart before you make the payment.

Comment: You say you can't but you you also say that if you add it to the cart, you'll be able to see if you can?